# MySQL and average of multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to return average for each of 12 columns I have in a table in DB. MySQL allows one to get average for one column only. The following query (for one column) works:

```
SELECT station_id, AVG(jan) AS avg_jan
FROM `climate_data`

WHERE element_name = "Temp_mean_mly" AND jan <> -999999  
GROUP BY station_id
```

and the following (for multiple columns) does not (I get syntax error):

```
SELECT station_id, AVG(jan) AS avg_jan, AVG(feb) AS avg_feb, ... , 
AVG(dec) AS avg_dec 
FROM `climate_data`

WHERE element_name = "Temp_mean_mly" 
AND jan <> -999999 
AND feb <> -999999
AND ... 
AND dec <> -999999 
GROUP BY station_id
```

Do I have to use 12 sub-queries to achieve the result I need?

Comment: "Does not work" is kind of vague here. Could you at least tell us what you would expect the latter query to do and what it does do (wrong)?

Comment: Sure. I meant it cannot be parsed. Here is the error I get: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'dec) AS avg_dec FROM `climate_data`. When I try to get average for only one column it works fine.
WHERE element_name = &quot;Temp_mean_mly&quot; AND jan' at line 1

Comment: `DEC` is a reserved word according to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html. Put backticks around `dec`.

Comment: Are you sure about this query, even with accepted fix? cos it looks like you are trying to get the average of each month's data except where values are -99999. But your query **excludes all rows** that have **any** month with -99999 from **all** averages, which is very different. If you want to know how to do it, post here and un-accept the answer, and I'll post the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'dec)

dec is a reserved MySQL keyword; changing it to `dec` in your query would probably fix that error for you :).

Edit: note that you're also using it in the WHERE clause; it might work there (as it's unlogical for MySQL to find a keyword there), but keep it in mind that you might also have to escape that one :)

Comment: Yes, worked like a charm!:) Error codes are often not self-explanatory:)

Comment: Are you sure this worked? cos it looks like you are trying to get the average of the month's data except where values are -99999. Your query excludes all rows that have *any* month with -99999, which is very different. If you want to know how to do it, post here and un-accept this answer, and I'll post the solution.

Comment: Yes, you're right! Here is the new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6599136/mysql-and-average-of-multiple-columns-indivudual-condition-for-each-of-the-colu