# Average of multiple columns + indivudual condition for each of the columns

Tags: mysql

I have a following query:

```
SELECT `station_id`, AVG(`jan`) AS avg_jan, AVG(`feb`) AS avg_feb, ... , 
AVG(`dec`) AS avg_dec 
FROM `climate_data`

WHERE `element_name` = "Temp_mean_mly" 
AND `jan` <> -999999 
AND `feb` <> -999999
AND ... 
AND `dec` <> -999999 
GROUP BY station_id
```

I need it to return average of values different than -999999 for each of the columns individually! The current query eliminates all rows with any of columns having value -999999 which is not correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `NULLIF` like so:

```
SELECT 
    station_id, 
    AVG(NULLIF(jan, -99999)) AS avg_jan, 
    AVG(NULLIF(feb, -99999)) AS avg_feb,
    ...
FROM climate_data
WHERE element_name = 'Temp_mean_mly'
GROUP BY station_id
```

This works because aggregate functions skip NULL values.

Comment: doesn't work on my case.  i have the exact same problem but different matters